# C++ 2d array duplication error in game

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to figure out why I get two "*" symbols in my game board when I'm moving around. The game is supposed to be about avoiding the troll (@). But I am getting duplicate @ and * symbols, and I can't figure out why. It seems that the problem is either in one of the `for` loops or in the `posX` or `posY` variables, which I found out by commenting out segments of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void ClearScreen()
{
    cout << string(100, '\n');
}

main()
{
    int size_arrx = 10;
    int size_arry = 20;
    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    int trollX = size_arrx - 1;
    int trollY = size_arry - 1;
    char a[size_arry][size_arrx];
    bool Alive = true;
    char player = '*';
    char troll = '@';
    while (Alive == true) {
        ClearScreen();
        for (int i = 0; i<size_arrx; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<size_arry; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<size_arrx; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<size_arry; j++)
            {
                a[posX][posY] = player;
                a[trollX][trollY] = troll;

                cout << a[i][j];

                if (posX< 0) {
                    a[posX = 0][posY] = player;
                    cout << a[i][j];
                }
                else if (posY< 0) {
                    a[posX][posY = 0] = player;
                    cout << a[i][j];
                }
                else if (posY > size_arry - 1) {
                    a[posX][posY = size_arry - 1] = player;
                    cout << a[i][j];
                }
                else if (posX > size_arrx - 1) {
                    a[posX = size_arrx - 1][posY] = player;
                    cout << a[i][j];
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        char dir;
        cin >> dir;
        if (dir == 'w') {
            trollX++;
            posX--;
        }

        if (dir == 's') {
            trollX--;
            posX++;
        }

        if (dir == 'd') {
            trollY--;
            posY++;
        }

        if (dir == 'a') {
            trollY++;
            posY--;
        }
    }

    if ((trollX == posX) && (trollY == posY)) {
        Alive == false;
    }
}
```

The result looks like this. I only want one *. The * can move perfectly fine, but a duplicate * follows the original * but 11 X's away.

```
xxxxxxxxxx*xxxxxxxxx  <---- This is a duplicate *
*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@
xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx <---- This is a duplicate @
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me

```
for (int i=0;i<size_arrx;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<size_arry;j++){
        a[i][j]='x';
}
    }
a[posX][posY]=player;
a[trollX][trollY]=troll;
for (int i=0;i<size_arrx;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<size_arry;j++){
        cout << a[i][j];
```

Using this code gave the same error. I'm interpreting this as `a[i][j]='x'` populates all positions of `a[][]` with X's. `a[posX][posY]=player;` overwrites the position of the player with an * (could be x 2 y 5 for example) and then the board gets printed by `cout << a[i][j];`. I don't understand how a duplicate symbol gets thrown in there.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: please use proper indentation, the code is terrible to read

Comment: Looks like you are having issues with moving characters.  You need to keep track of the characters' previous location so you can restore it.

Comment: I recommend performing character positioning *before* you print the board.  The `posX` and `posY` don't depend on `i` or `j` and are not modified within either `for` loop.  Keep the board printing simple and focused.

Comment: `>for (int i=0;i<size_arrx;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<size_arry;j++)
{
    a[i][j]='x';
}
}
    a[posX][posY]=player;
    a[trollX][trollY]=troll;
for (int i=0;i<size_arrx;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<size_arry;j++)
{

    cout << a[i][j];
`
using this code gave the same error. I'm interpreting this as a[i][j]='x' populates all positions of a[][] with X's.
a[posX][posY]=player; overwrites the position of the player with an * (could be x 2 y 5 for example) and then the board gets printed by     cout << a[i][j];. I dont understand how a duplicate symbol gets thrown in there.

Comment: Whether or not this solves your current problem, you really have to correct the position to stay on the board and right after the move and set the players position right after resetting the board and not during the display loop.

Comment: @jarlow: please look at your previous comment.  Pasting code in a comment is very difficult to read.  However, editing your post with the code, makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your program.

Initialize the board outside of the while loop.
There should be no reason to keep initializing it:

```
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < size_arry; ++row)
{
  std::fill(&a[row][0], &a[row][size_arrx], 'x'); // Fill a row.
}
```

Printing the board should be simple:

```
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < size_arry; ++row)
{
  for (unsigned int column = 0; column < size_arrx; ++column)
  {
    cout << a[row][column];
  }
  cout << '\n';
}
```

Now the character logic.
Every character has a *position*, row and column, of where it is.  To ease restoration, every character should have a previous position also.

```
struct Position
{
  unsigned int row;
  unsigned int column;
};
```

*Sorry about that code, the fingers and keyboard are not cooperating.*

To move a character to a valid new position, you have to restore the previous position:

```
unsigned int player_now_x;
unsigned int player_now_y;
unsigned int player_prev_x;
unsigned int player_prev_y;
//...
a[player_prev_y][player_prev_x] = 'x';
a[player_now_y][player_now_y] = player;
```

For processing single letter commands, a `switch` statement may be more readable:

```
// Update previous position.
player_prev_x = player_now_x;
player_prev_y = player_now_y;
switch (dir)
{
  case 'd':
    if (player_now_y < size_arry)
    {
      ++player_now_y;
    }
    break;
  case 's':
    if (player_now_x < size_arrx)
    {
      ++player_now_x;
    }
    break;
// ...
  }
```

Simplifications.
You can print the board with one `cout` if you add an extra column.  The ending column of each row (except the last) will have a line ending character, '\n'.  The last column of the last row will have a termination character, '\0'.

```
struct Board
{
  void set_player(const Position& pos, char player_token)
  {
    a[pos.x][pos.y] = player_token;
  }

  void move_player(const Position& new_position,
                   const Position& previous_position,
                   char            player_token)
  {
     set_player(previous_position, 'x');
     set_player(new_position, player_token);
  }

  void print()
  {
    std::cout << &a[0][0] << "\n";
  }

  Board()
  {
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < size_arry; ++y)
    {
      std::fill(&a[y][0], &a[y][size_arrx], 'x');
      a[y][size_arrx - 1] = '\n';
    }
    a[size_arry - 1][size_arrx - 1] = '\0';
  }
};

//...
Board b;
Position player_now;
Position player_prev;
const char player_token = '*';

//...
switch (dir)
{
  case 'd':
    if (player_now.y < size_arry)
    {
       ++player_now.y;
    }
  //...
}
b.move_player(player_now, player_previous, player_token);
```

*Sorry again, for the above code fragment, it's the fingers typing out what they want.*